# cannot assign script to a button on google spreadsheet, How can I assign a script to a button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanted to create a button with (insert -> drawing) and then assign a script to this button.
But it don't work.
whatever the script name or content is, when I try to assign to a button on any spreadsheet on my computer, I fail with the same message. Here is an example with a simple script :

here the script "SHOW" that I want to insert
[image]

the script in my script library :
[image]

the error message : "the script function SHOW cannot be found"
[image]

I know it should work, because I did it with a test spreadsheet few weeks ago it works, but it no longer work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try renaming the function to SHOW. Or, try putting SHOW_ALL in the Assigned Script on the drawing. It looks like there's a mismatch between the Script function you are assigning to the drawing and the actual function in Apps Script.

```
function SHOW() {
//Function contents
}
```